# How would I create a scatter plot in R like the one below in excel? (See picture and my attempt at using R)

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am interested in creating a scatter plot with the following data using R:

| Minutes | Group 1 | Group 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 199 | 176 |
| 2 | 188 | 157 |
| 3 | 169 | 144 |

See screenshot for more info:

https://joshuawkelly.notion.site/Question-about-r-777cd223ed1441afb1f23dece3b9bc9c?pvs=4

I began to write the code for the graph, but then I ran into issues. Namely: (1) how to put multiple sets of data on a single graph, and (2) how to adjust the graph to be within intended ranges and scales.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
fnames = c(1, 2, 3)
g1 = c(119, 118, 157)
g2 = c(176, 157, 144)
    
hr_data_class = tibble(Minutes = fnames,Group_1 = g1,Group_2 = g2)

print(hr_data_class)

ggplot(hr_data_class, aes(x=fnames,, y=g1 + g2, color=cyl, shape=cyl)) + geom_point(shape=6, color= "#154734") + labs(x="Time (Minutes)",y="Heart Rate (BPM)")

ggplot(hr_data_class, aes(x=g1,, y=g2, color=cyl, shape=cyl)) + geom_point(shape=6, color= "#154734") + labs(x="Time (Minutes)",y="Heart Rate (BPM)")

plot(fnames,g1,col='red',pch=19,cex=3,xlab='X1',ylab='Y1',main='hello world')

plot(fnames,g2,col='red',pch=19,cex=3,xlab='Time (Minutes)',ylab='Heart Rate (BPM)',main='Class Heart Rate Data')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the values for the groups are spread across columns you could use a `geom_point` for each column but the `tidyverse` way would be to reshape your data to long or tidy format using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer` which allows to create your plot using one `geom_point`. The colors can then be set via `scale_color_manual`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

hr_data_class_long <- hr_data_class |>
  pivot_longer(-Minutes, names_to = "group", values_to = "value")

ggplot(hr_data_class_long, aes(Minutes, value, color = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  labs(x = "Time (Minutes)", y = "Heart Rate (BPM)", color = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]